# Understanding tomcat/spring boot multi threading

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, tomcat

I've created a simple web application on the base of spring-boot. It gets request, do some block operations (like writing to the console numbers from 1 to 10_000) and returns simple response.
When I start to test it with JVisual VM I've noticed that threads work in a strange way.
In the beginning, with low load, they don't work at the same time, they work in turn:

[image: load test 1]

If I try to high-load application than Tomcat creates new Threads (It's OK as I understand) and after time threads work at the same time:

[image: load test 2]

I've used [Netling](https://github.com/hallatore/Netling) app to test application. It just simple request on localhost, nothing special.
Could you please explain why it works in this way? Or provide some links with description.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Requests are queued, as long as the current number of started threads can empty the queue quick enough no additional threads will be started. Your image also shows that in both cases they work at the same time (see threads 10, 7 and 4

Comment: @M.Deinum. Thanks for your explanation. You exactly right about the first screenshot, it's my fault, but I've not seen this situation on all tests before

Comment: @M.Deinum Also, the question is not about queue and pool size. Main question is Why all threads don't work at the same time?

Comment: Why should they? If there is no work, why should they do something...Also the number of concurrent running threads is limited by the number of cores you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've understood the root of the issue. 
On the JVisualVM I saw, that all Threads was blocked by each other, but I didn't know why. Now it's clear - I've use system.out.println() as a block operation, but Threads can't use it at the same time, the console is locked.
I've change console output to file output (use thread name as a filename to prevent lock) and start the application again. Now it's work as expected.

Stupid mistake, but I hope it will be useful for someone :)

[image]